# Extract negative values from a column

Tags: r, integer

I have read in a table with 5 columns and 200 rows into **R** - I want to have the indices in a vector of ten rows which have a negative value in my fifth column - is that somehow possible?

My table is called r. 
I know I can extract the fifth row by:

```
r[,5]
```

but I don't know how I can then exclude all positive value, or get the indexes of the negative values in the column

Comment: Taking a look at some introductory R texts, e.g. http://cran.r-project.org/manuals.html, should get you your answer.

Comment: isn't there a quick single commadn lien thing for that - i know its introductory btu it woudl eb great if somebody could briefly outlien it

Comment: Yes, it is possible using simple data frame indexing (conditional). Post a reproducible example if you try & still fail.

Comment: @TimHeinert I can give you the answer straightaway, but you'll learn more from finding it yourself.

Answer (score 3):

```
# *** Get some test data ***
> con <- textConnection(Lines <- "
+ First, Last, Email, CustomerSince, Balance, RiskFactor
+ Alan, Appleton, aa@google.com,1992, -100,  3
+ Bob, Bates, BobB@yahoo.com,1997, 231,  2
+ Charles, Clemson, Chuck@Clemson.com,2001, -4.2,  1
+ Dennis, Delgado, dd@hotmail.com,2004, 27,  1
+ Ernesto, Ellonka, Ernie@hotmail.com,2010, 40.5,  6
+ ")
> x <- read.csv(con)
> close(con)
# *** That's what our data looks like.  5th column is numeric
> x
    First      Last              Email CustomerSince Balance RiskFactor
1    Alan  Appleton      aa@google.com          1992  -100.0          3
2     Bob     Bates     BobB@yahoo.com          1997   231.0          2
3 Charles   Clemson  Chuck@Clemson.com          2001    -4.2          1
4  Dennis   Delgado     dd@hotmail.com          2004    27.0          1
5 Ernesto   Ellonka  Ernie@hotmail.com          2010    40.5          6

# *** And here's how to get a vector of all indexes of the Balance column
# *** that have a negative value
> x["Balance"] < 0
     Balance
[1,]    TRUE
[2,]   FALSE
[3,]    TRUE
[4,]   FALSE
[5,]   FALSE
> 
# *** And here's how to directly exclude the positive balance from the list
> x[x$Balance < 0, ]
First      Last              Email CustomerSince Balance RiskFactor
1    Alan  Appleton      aa@google.com          1992  -100.0          3
3 Charles   Clemson  Chuck@Clemson.com          2001    -4.2          1

# to just get the list of indexes that match that criteria, you can use which()
> which(x$Balance < 0)
[1] 1 3
```

Comment: great ...however, I wanted to have the numerical values in a vector ...so just the row numbers of the rows which have a negative value in the fifth column

Comment: Ah, didn't see you added the answer at the end. I'm deleting my answer and +1 for you

Comment: @SimonO101, thks for +1, and very classy to delete your answer! 
In many ways your answer is better because more to the point...  In the case of quasi simultaneous answers - my edit was only about 2 minutes before your answer-  I think it is quite ok to leave both answers.

Comment: @mjv your answer has a lot of useful explanation surrounding it which will be useful to others who google this kind of problem. My answer was only really useful to the OP, so this is better really.